# Table gets auto-cleared when session is closed in OracleDB

Tags: database, oracle, select, plsql, oracle19c

I have this oracle db instance

```
C:\> set ORACLE_SID=orcl;
C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba
```

When I am creating table and adding few rows in it

```
SQL> SELECT table_name
     FROM user_tables
     ORDER BY table_name;

SQL> INSERT ALL  
     INTO customers (customer_id , customer_name, city  ) VALUES (1, 'Aman', 'Ranchi')
     INTO customers (customer_id , customer_name, city  ) VALUES (2, 'Akib', 'Purulia') 
     SELECT * FROM dual;
```

[image]

```
SQL> UPDATE customers  
     SET customer_name = 'Aashi'
     WHERE customer_id = 1;
```

Now when I am logging out/quitting

```
SQL > Ctrl^C
```

And logging in again, This is what I am getting `no rows selected`

[image]

Why were my changes not affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you neglected to `commit` your changes.  When you forcibly terminated `SQL*Plus` rather than gracefully logging out, Oracle rolled back your changes.

Separately, if you are going to create objects in your database, please don't log in as `sys` or create them in the `sys` schema (or the `system` tablespace).  Create a new user that will own your objects, create a tablespace for user objects for that user to use, and log in as that user to create the objects.  Creating objects in the `sys` schema isn't supported and there are features that behave differently in `sys` than they do elsewhere.

Comment: If I create a new schema, how do I access those tables that I already created in the sys schema?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - Realistically, you'd want to drop whatever objects you've created in `sys` and create them in the new schema.  You could use the `export` and `import` utilities to do that but it's probably just as easy to open `SQL Developer` and just script out whatever objects you want to move over.

Comment: I didn't understand one thing tho, why do we need to run `SELECT * FROM dual;` after every insert

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - You don't.  You could just as easily run two separate `insert ... values` statements to insert two rows of data.  If you want to run an `insert all` statement, you need to select data from somewhere.  Since you're not actually using the data you're selecting, selecting from `dual` is the easiest option.

Comment: "you need to select data from somewhere." what exactly do you mean by this, the data that I am inserting is already provided in the command, isn't it. What data is dual trying to insert?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - You are choosing to use an `insert all` statement which is supposed to be used to select data from one table and insert it into one or more tables.  You happen to have built the `insert all` statement such that it doesn't actually use the data that it is selecting.  You could instead have just used two simple `insert ... values` statement `INSERT INTO customers (customer_id , customer_name, city  ) VALUES (1, 'Aman', 'Ranchi')`.

Comment: So why aren't dual data also getting pushed into the table? since it has only 1r1c why aren't we ggeting error while inserting the same?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - I have no idea what "1r1c" means.  You aren't inserting data from `dual` because neither of your `values` clauses includes a column from `dual`.  If you want to have a longer discussion about the mechanics of the `insert all` statement, that is probably more appropriate in a separate question rather than in comments.